# WSUS Crashes when a high ressource query is performed

Tags: iis, sql-server, windows-server-2016, wsus

We have been implementing a WSUS Server on Windows Server 2016 several times and it works well in the beginning but stops working after all updates (~130.000) have been downloaded and approved. We are running it with MSSQL instead of the internal database.

When all updates have been downloaded I'm not abble to show and approve all updates at a time. When I try to do so the WSUS Server crashes. At that point a client talking to the server doesn't impact its functionality. I then wrote a script to approve all the updates in smaller steps which worked. But after all the updates have been approved for our clients every contact with a client crashes the WSUS Service.

Strangly enogh when I only approve the important updates at first (which are only ~15.000) everything works perfectly fine which again points to a kind of bottleneck.

My suspicion is that the WSUS Service crashes at that point because the WSUS server has to process the information from the client against all the approved updates in the database which then crashes the WSUS service. Strangly neither the ISS nor the SQL-Server are really crashing.

Does anybody have similar expiriences or a viable solution?

Comment: `1.` By "allow" do you mean "approve"? `2.` Surely you don't actually need every update for every classification for every product? That seems counterproductive. I've seen WSUS implementations at several multi-national companies and none of them downloaded nor approved every update for every classification for every product.

Comment: `1.` You are right I fixed the text accordingly. `2.` We did not download every update but did only select a subset of the available products. But as we have a very diverse environment with some older systems we need to provide a lot of updates.

Comment: This is a common issue. Increase the speed of the sql server, reduce unneeded updates and run maintenance regularly. Increase the WSUS app pool private memory available, or increase the ASP.net timeout value.

Comment: @Appleoddity Thank you very much! The problem was in fact related to the memory of the IIS app pool. If you answer my question I'm going to mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was in fact an IIS related prolem. The private memory available to the IIS app pool was to small. (As pointed out by @Appleoddity) After giving it three times the default available memory the WSUS service does now run perfectly well.